# WordPress, query not finding related posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have three posts, two which have the tag `eGuide` one which has the tag `Article`. When I click on an `eGuide`, I want the sidebar to display other eGuide's (up to 2) and nothing else. To do this, I have the following query:

```
global $post;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID ),
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__not_in'   => array($post->ID )
);
$relatedPosts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But it's showing the `article` too? I've also tried:

```
'post__not_in'   => array(get_the_ID() )
```

... still no luck.

Comment: Category and Tag are different things. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $post;

$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'your_taxonomy_here', array( "fields" => "ids", "parent" => 0 ) );

$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_here',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term_list[0],
        ),
    ),
);
$relatedPosts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can try this code to get related posts.